How to properly configure appsettings.json, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and .env for a .NET open-source project with Docker?
I am developing an open-source project in .NET, and I want to containerize it using Docker. I am facing confusion regarding how to configure and organize different files like appsettings.json, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and .env for this project.
It feels like each of these files could potentially hold the same configuration values, but I am unsure of the best practices for splitting the configuration across them.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

appsettings.json: Store application-specific settings (e.g., connection strings, logging settings).
Dockerfile: Containerize the .NET application, install dependencies, and configure runtime environment.
docker-compose.yml: Orchestrate the container setup for multiple services (e.g., API, database).
.env: Manage environment-specific settings that vary across development, staging, and production.

Could someone please clarify:

The best practices for splitting configurations across these files.
How to pass values from .env to appsettings.json or docker-compose.yml.
How to configure each file for different environments (development, production).

Any guidance or sample configuration files would be greatly appreciated!
